# Don't match Regex when ends with pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am attempting to write an regex patten which will match a url only if it doesn't end with a specific pattern. I was able to get it to work with lookbehind, but its not widely enough supported yet on some browsers. Looking for an alternative. I was attempting something like below, but no luck. Appreciate the help.

https://regex101.com/r/4halPB/1

```
^([a-z]*:)?\/\/([a-z0-9-]+)(\.([a-z0-9-]+))*(:(\d+))?(.+)(?!#some_pattern$)$
```

match input: https://google.com/some/

not match input: https://google.com/some/#some_pattern

Comment: You should put the negative lookahead at the beginning of the pattern. [`^(?!.*#some_pattern$)([a-z]*:)?\/\/([a-z0-9-]+)(\.([a-z0-9-]+))*(:(\d+))?(.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/mYPeyb/1)

Comment: @HaoWu that did it. Thank you for your help! Would you mind explaining why this works for clarification.